# Unity3D inside Qt on Linux

Tags: linux, qt, unity-game-engine

Is it possible to have a Unity3D application play inside a window in a Qt application on Linux?

I have to find a way to put a realtime 3D view into an existing Qt application. (Or at least make it look like that's what's happening)

Has anyone done anything similar or can point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Qt Canvas 3D` which provides a way to make OpenGL-like 3D drawing calls from `Qt Quick JavaScript`. I hope [this link](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcanvas3d-getting-started.html) will help you to get started and setup the environment.